# Reduce noise on segmented image regions

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm working on a `Python 3.10` image segmentation project that relies on K-Means clustering to reduce the palette complexity of the original image.

This is my clustering function:

```
def segment_image(image_path):
  data = cv2.imread(image_path)
  o_image = cv2.cvtColor(data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # Convert to RGB
  image = cv2.medianBlur(o_image, 5) # Smooth image
  arr = image.reshape((-1, 3)) # Underlying numpy array
  values = np.float32(arr)

  k = elbow(arr) # Automatic definition of K according to Elbow Method
  print('Using {} clusters.'.format(k))
  kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = k, random_state=11, init = 'k-means++', n_init='auto').fit(arr) # K-Means

  labels = kmeans.labels_.flatten() # Get labels
  centers = np.uint8(kmeans.cluster_centers_) # Centroids
  less_colors = centers[labels.flatten()].reshape(data.shape) # Generate clustered image

  cv2.imshow(less_colors) # Show result
```

For a given image, a sample result is shown below (In this instance, K = 5):

**Original Image**
[image: Input]

**Clustered Regions**
[image: Clustered]

While the image has been significantly simplified and the K-Means labels already provide helpful segmentation (light-blue for lemons, dark-blue for pomegranate), the resulting image still contains a lot of noise, specially around object edges and on the smaller details of the written text.

This means that when manipulating the original image to show only the areas represented by *light blue (lemons)*, we get this:

**Only "lemon region" enabled**
[image: Clustered Region]

Thus, what additional image processing techniques can I introduce to improve the final region segmentation quality? I have tried `cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored()`, which severely degraded the clarity of the proposed regions.

Comment: target is segmenting the fruits only ?

Comment: Correct, my goal is to segment potential 'areas of interest'. In this case, the fruit is my target.